# cannot "Add or Update" Entity because Primery key cannot be changed

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I am implementing an import routine, where a user pastes a specific formatted string into an input field, which in turn gets tranformated into an entity and then put into a database.

The algorithm checks if the entity already exists and either tries to update it or insert it into the database. Inserting works fine - updating fails.

```
//considered existing if Name and owning user match.
if (db.Captains.Any(cpt => cpt.Name == captain.Name && cpt.User.Id == UserId))
{
    var captainToUpdate = db.Captains.Where(cpt => cpt.Name == captain.Name && cpt.User.Id == UserId).SingleOrDefault();

    db.Entry(captainToUpdate).CurrentValues.SetValues(captain);
    db.Entry(captainToUpdate).State = EntityState.Modified;
    await db.SaveChangesAsync();
 }
```

The problem at hand is, that written like this, it tries to update the primary key as well, (`captain` Id is 0, whereas `captainToUpdate` Id is already set) which results in an exception `The property 'Id' is part of the object's key information and cannot be modified.`

What do I need to change, so the enttiy gets updated properly. If it can be avoided I don't want to update every property by hand, because the table Captain contains 30ish columns.

Comment: Why not note the key value before setting values. Then reset key back.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would not use the entity `Captain` to transfer the data to the UI, but a DTO object that has all properties you want to copy and no more. *You can copy values from any object.* All matching properties will be copied, all other properties in `captainToUpdate` will not be affected.

Comment: If it is any use. I'm transferring data FROM the UI to the server. It is a string, which gets parsed and pressed into a entity type captain, because that is what fits most. Shy of ID and navigatonal properties.

Comment: Doesn't really matter, you can always use a DTO type. One way or another you'll have to tell which properties should copy. AutoMapper (configuring ignored properties) could do the job as well.

Comment: The problem with DTO type is that you would need *two* nearly identical ones, one for updating (-IDs) and the other for everyhing else (you still need to indentify entity in UI for say, deleting).

Comment: I wouldn't say it's a "problem". It's a *consequence* of a design choice.

Answer (score 3):

What you can do is first set the Id of captain to be the same as the Id of captainToUpdate:

```
captain.Id = captainToUpdate.Id;
db.Entry(captainToUpdate).CurrentValues.SetValues(captain);
await db.SaveChangesAsync();
```

Comment: This gave me the clue to find the problem :)

Comment: Thank you. Very helpful. So in summary : 
Before calling the CurrentValues.SetValues statement, first assign the Id of the object from UI to be the same as the object from the db .

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this ?

```
var captainToUpdate = db.Captains.FirstOrDefault(cpt => cpt.Name == captain.Name &&     cpt.User.Id == UserId);
if(captainToUpdate != null){//Update captain Here
    captainToUpdate.Update(captain);        
}else{//Create captain here
    db.Captains.Add(captain);
}
db.Savechanges();
```

Comment: that of course is a valid solution, but as stated in my last sentence, I am looking for a way which avoides excactly this. I don't want to update 30+ properties by hand.

Comment: You only have to add the code to upgrade those properties once. I recently had to write similar code for 10 entities with 10-80 properties each, with special behaviour like converting optionsets and booleans. Sometimes you'll have to do something you don't want to do.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and solved it by extension method and reflection, of course it will be better to create standalone class with some cachning for relfection, but performance wasn't  critical in my task.

```
public static class EnitityFrameworkHelper
    {
        public static void SetValuesByReflection(this DbPropertyValues propertyValues, object o, IEnumerable<string> properties = null)
        {
            var reflProperties = o.GetType().GetProperties();
            var prop = properties ?? propertyValues.PropertyNames;
            foreach (var p in prop)
            {
                var refp = reflProperties.First(x => x.Name == p);
                var v= refp.GetValue(o);
                propertyValues[p] = v;
            }
        }
    }
```

and here is example how to use it

```
 var entry = ctx.Entry(accSet);
 entry.CurrentValues.SetValuesByReflection(eParameters, entry.CurrentValues.PropertyNames.Except(new [] { "ID"}));
```

Also be careful with foreign keys in object which you want to update, probably you want to exclude them too.